# How to Rotate Plot Labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

How can I make the top labels on the plot below vertical so they can be read and not overlap each other?

The code I used to create the plot is:

```
indexnames2 = {05730, Q2774, 05453, 27202, 03689, 27367, 09747, 14922,
    54785, 07884, 02659, 06749, 08731};
ticks2 = Transpose[{Range[Length[indexnames2]], indexnames2}];
MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 FrameTicks -> {ticks2, None, None, ticks2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, RotateLabel -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[seqgroupname, FontSize -> 18]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `ticks=Table[{i, Rotate[i,Pi/4]},{i,1,num}]`

Comment: @Rom38 That removed all of my tick marks.  I have edited my question to show how my labels are set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
outtabletoprint = RandomReal[1, {13, 13}];

MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 FrameTicks -> {ticks2, None, None, MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &, ticks2, {All, 2}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Works great.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jamie,  my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.